# Trigger Ctrl+P printing for a JQuery Modal Box through keyboard

Tags: jquery, printing, modal-dialog

I have a document which pops up on the site within a JQuery Modal Box. The document has a print button at the end which just prints the document in the Pop-Up Box.

I am looking to find a solution that I can print the pop-up box by pressing Ctrl+P. Right now Ctrl+p prints all the page including the background ... I am just hoping to find a solution which helps me print the document in the pop-up only.

My JQuery Modal Box is in iFrame and is shown in the following way:-

```
<div id="frameContainer">
      <iframe id="lightboxFrame" width="950px" scrolling="auto" height="500px">
         <!DOCTYPE html>
           <html>
             <head>
                <body> (Whole Document in a Div) </body>
             ...
```

This is the DIV in the pop-up HTML that prints the pop-up document.

```
<div id="edit-actions" class="form-actions form-wrapper">
   <input id="print-submit" class="form-submit" value="Print this Survey" name="print" onclick="printAssessment()" type="button" />
</div>
```

This is what I did:-

```
 $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey==true && (event.which == '80')) { //cntrl + p
            event.preventDefault();
            printAssessment();
        }
    });

    function printAssessment() {
        //alert("Print the little page");
        window.print();
    }
```

The function is definitely being called when I press Ctrl+P but it still prints the whole page. I want that it prints only the Modal Box. Weirdly, when I press the print button inside the Modal Box, which uses the same function, it prints correctly.

Thanks,

FIRST EDIT:-

Partially working now.

When I changed the function of PrintAssessment() to the following, it works:-

```
  function printAssessment() {

        window.frames["lightboxFrame"].focus();
        window.frames["lightboxFrame"].print();

    }
```

But, the weird thing is that It prints when I click Ctrl+P only the first time. When I try to print again, it keeps giving me this error:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'print' of undefined
```

or

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'focus' of undefined
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should use : $('#lightboxFrame')[0].contentWindow.print();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
 window.print();
```

You can print the content of the iframe like following :

```
$('#lightboxFrame')[0].contentWindow.print();
```

Put the code bellow in your function printAssessment()

Comment: Hi Anass, thanks for your comment. But somehow it doesn't work. Should I put this code in the printAssessment() function? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but same problem. On first try, it prints fine. One second try, it gives me the error of :- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined

Comment: Work like charm here, it seems like after the first control + P he is not able to find lightboxFrame. purhaps your are removing this somewhere ??

Comment: Is the Pop up still open in the second try ??

Comment: Yes, Imagine the frustration. I even shaked my display, just in case.

Comment: Upping your answer, it was still useful. Would be thankful if you could comment on that weird error.

Comment: 90% sure the problem is coming from .focus(); Remove it and try again normaly it should works !

Comment: Thanks a lot Anass. Actually I used your code and it still gave that weird behavior. Nonetheless, thanks a lot for your time.