# Trigger a keypress event manually for a combination like Ctrl+P in angular/javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, keypress, ctrlp

How to trigger a keypress event manually for a combination like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in angular/javascript?

I have tried using the `window.print()` method. But unfortunately, I have some css styles to be applied for the document to be printed in the @media print{} in css. The same style gets applied to the parent page as the one in print window.

Issue does not occur when clicking `ctrl+p`. The print window has separate styles applied, different from the original page in this case.

Comment: So calling `window.print()` ignores the media rule, but pressing Ctrl+P doesn't? Can you create a [mre]? That almost sounds like a browser bug.

Comment: Below might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893397/how-to-trigger-key-combo-with-jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304538/trigger-ctrlp-printing-for-a-jquery-modal-box-through-keyboard Thanks.

Comment: window.print() applies the css rule to both the print window as well as the page in background. But ctrl+p does not behave like that. It applies the css rule only to the print window.

Comment: @MehulGayate Im trying to figure out a javascript version for compination keypress.

Comment: This one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically